# Bootstrap 4 Nav Item Stacking

Tags: html, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a Nav bar with the menu fixed to the left-hand side, nav brand centered and a shopping cart and search icon fixed to the right. However, when I scale down to mobile, the icons on the right stack. How can i fix this?

```html
<div className="container">
  <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded navbar-toggleable-sm">
    <button className="navbar-toggler mr-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span className="navbar-toggler-icon" />
              </button>

    <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" href="/">
                HOMF
              </a>

    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <i class="fas fa-search" />
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <i class="fas fa-search" />
      </li>
    </ul>

    <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul className="navbar-nav ml-auto text-center">
        <li className="nav-item">
          <NavLink to="/" className="nav-link">
            MENS
          </NavLink>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item">
          <NavLink to="/" className="nav-link">
            WOMENS
          </NavLink>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item">
          <NavLink to="/" className="nav-link">
            KIDS
          </NavLink>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: is there really a <navlink> tag? shouldn't it be <a class="nav-link"> ?

Comment: im using react NavLink to route to pages

Comment: What is the display property of these navlink tags in the resulting source ?

Comment: a {
    color: #007bff;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: transparent;
}

Comment: even with just " <a class="nav-link"> " they seem to be stacking when it hits mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`navbar-nav` has `white-space:nowrap` as wrapping property, try replacing `navbar-nav` by simply `nav` on the parent `<ul>` tag which will add a `display:flex` and `flex-wrap:wrap` property to your ul element